# Hadoop Streaming Job v/s Hadoop pipe job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to run a hadoop job using following command

hadoop -jar myjob.jar

In this case i can not see the jar submitted and its status using web page(at port 50030)

but if i do

hadoop jar myjob.jar

I can see the progress on the same port(50030)

What is the difference between these two commands ,I searched a bit and found

hadoop -jar to submit pipe jobs

hadoop jar to submit streaming jobs

Any insight will be of a great help.

Comment: Are you sure about `hadoop -jar`? I'm quite sure this does nothing because there is no such command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `hadoop -jar`

From [the docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html):

Usage: `hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args...`

> The streaming jobs are run via this command.